# Magento saving issues after move to new server and new domain

Tags: php, database, magento

I recently moved my magento store from a server using one domain name to a new host/server with another domain name. DNS has not been changed on the new domain yet so I am using my host file to work on the site.

After the move, I make changes to product descriptions or CMS Page
Click Save and it says that it was saved, however, after saving, changes show on frontend of site immediately but don't show in the admin unless I log out and log back in.

I am unable to delete text in CMS page or product descriptions at all without going into phpMyAdmin and removing the text from the database.

Any ideas what this might be?

Comment: Check your console, find the request you made, inspect the response code, response status, and response text to identify what could possibly be wrong. This is too broad, however, and I'm voting to close.

Comment: Voting to close?  How does someone get help if not for asking questions.

Comment: Didn't mean to hit send yet. Not sure where I can find the response codes?  Is it in System Config somewhere?

Comment: Open your web inspector in your browser (chrome is F12). Then, hit "preserve log" at the top, so all network requests will be preserved. Then find the request by URL, click, and inspect. We understand you need help, but this isn't about coding, this is about a MagentoCMS migration going awry, which is most likely a software specific setting or a server configuration issue. With that in mind, when you can find some specific piece of code you're having trouble with, that's when you come here. Stackoverflow isn't like a forum site, which is how you're question would need to be treated. Goodluck.